# List of aircraft which are not certified to be flown by one pilot

Tags: faa

Is there a list somewhere, where it says which aircraft are not single pilot certified?

My question is motivated by this question:

[Fine for operating not single-pilot certified jet with one pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57585/fine-for-operating-not-single-pilot-certified-jet-with-one-pilot)

Comment: It may be easier to come up with a list of them that *are* certified single-pilot, and assume that the rest are not. I'd also try to narrow this down, almost all GA light-aircraft (under 12,500lbs) are certified single-pilot.

Comment: @Ron Thanks!  I guess I meant aircraft with twin controls that are not allowed to be operated with a single pilot?  Isn't that the shorter list?

Comment: @curious_cat Most general aviation aircraft (Pipers, Cessnas, Mooneys, etc.) have dual controls and are certified for single pilot operation. Right off the top of my head, I can’t think of a single-engine turboprop that requires two pilots. When you get into light jets though, you start to see some that require two pilots and some that require only one. Cirrus and Cessna Mustang only require one pilot as do some of the Cessna Citation series.

Comment: @JScarry Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. But is there a list where this is defined? What's the canonical reference for this? Is there a FAA document that lists this, any idea?

Comment: @curious_cat There is no list that I know of. You might want to start a Wikipedia page to list them. Searching for light jet, VLJ, single pilot would get you started. There probably aren’t more than a dozen or so at the moment.

Comment: @curious_cat There are also a lot of twin-engine turbo-props that were flown by the airlines as two pilot but are now flown by freight outfits as single pilot. There are a couple of Metroliners that UPS uses on our field and I’d imagine lots of SAAB and Beech 1900 commuters too.

Comment: @JScarry So did the certification criterion change when they were sold by the airlines to the freight outfits? Or were they always rated to be flown by single pilot but airlines always flew with two?

Comment: @curious_cat Airlines have different rules than Part 91 and freight operations. e.g . §121.385(c) The minimum pilot crew is two pilots. The rules for the freight operations dictate how many pilots are required—subject to the minimum number of pilots in the airplane certification. So the certification of the airplane hasn’t changed, but the rules under which they fly has.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any list off hand but the [FAA publishes all their type certificates here](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/Frameset?OpenPage) which do contain the relevant information needed to compile such a list. As mentioned in the comments *most* small GA planes are single pilot certified so if we start with that assumption you will find a lot of lists that cover the topic of *"the largest single pilot certified aircraft"* [like this one](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/august/pilot/turbine-single-pilot-directory). These lists provide you with the ones that are on the fence size/speed wise.